# Mongodb query slow with dot notation

Tags: mongodb

I have this doc structure:

```
{
  "key": {
    "a": Int32,
    "b": String
  }
}
```

with a unique index on `key` and indexes (non-unique) on `key.a` and `key.b`.

Yet, this query scans (slooow):

```
{"key.a": 456213154}
```

and this query does not:

```
{"key": {
  "a": 456213154,
  "b": {"$exists": true}
}}
```

Why is that necessary, and should it be?

(I should mention that this is v2.0.3)

EDIT: adding explain:

```
> db.collection.find({"key.a": 456213154}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor key.a_1",
        "nscanned" : 10962,
        "nscannedObjects" : 10962,
        "n" : 10962,
        "millis" : 20,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "key.a" : [
                        [
                                456213154,
                                456213154
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
> db.collection.find({"key": {"a": 456213154, "b": {"$exists":true}}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor key_1",
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "key" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "a" : 456213154,
                                        "b" : {
                                                "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "a" : 456213154,
                                        "b" : {
                                                "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

EDIT: I tried removing the two non-unique indices (`key.a_1` and `key.b_1`) to see if that perhaps was hurting the query. It was not:

```
> db.collection.find({"key.a": 456213154}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 23240518,
        "nscannedObjects" : 23240518,
        "n" : 10962,
        "millis" : 15047,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the output of an `explain()` run on both queries?  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain

Comment: According to the `explain` output, you've got 10962 docs where `'key.a'` is 456213154, and none of them have a `key.b` field.  Is that correct?

Comment: all `key` sub-docs have both `a` and `b`, always. There's no use case for any of them to be either missing or `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `explain()` outputs suggest that:

1. There are 10962 objects that have `key.a : 456213154`.  Your `db.collection.find({"key.a": 456213154})` query used the index on `key.a`, and returned 10962 objects.
2. There are 0 objects in your collection that have `key.a : 456213154` and have `key.b : { $exists : true }`.  The `db.collection.find({"key": {"a": 456213154, "b": {"$exists":true}}})` query did use your index on key.

See the `n` value for each query - this is the number returned; and the `cursor` value - this is `BtreeCursor` if an index is used.  In this case it would make sense why the first query takes much longer, because it has significantly more objects to return.

Are you sure that the documents with `key.a : 456213154` values also have `key.b` values?

Edit:

The query with the `$exists` param is the wrong syntax for checking existence within embedded documents.

Try `db.collection.find({ "key.a" : 456213154, "key.b" : { "$exists" : true } })`.

Comment: You are correct, the second query returns no results. So the `$exists` part does not match anything. So the question is, how would I write something that matches? I tried `{"$ne":null}` also, no match.

Comment: It seems as if all your documents with key.a equal to 456213154 have no key.b field.  Am I correct?  In that case the $exists part should not match anything.

Comment: No, as I wrote earlier, `a` and `b` are always populated. I guess this is what threw me off, because I assumed the query would match, as written.

Comment: If they are both always populated, why is the $exists field necessary in your query?  The explain output is showing that the first query is as efficient as it can be, index-wise.

Comment: I added `$exists` because mongo otherwise won't match (incomplete object). But I guess it won't match anyway.

Comment: Right, but then it's unnecessary. I guess what I was trying to do does not work. Thanks.
(I'll probably remove this item since it was wrong and not of much use to anyone.)

Comment: Not to be unreasonable, but would you mind leaving it and accepting my answer, so I don't lose the rep :)?